# Beginner servlet deployment question: how to make third-party library access files in .war?

Tags: file, servlets, war

I get "Error opening ... file ... (No such file or directory)". However I do not control the file access - a third-party library is trying to open a file in the .war.

It works fine when using an open directory structure on my own computer.

My question is: is normal file access supposed to work within a .war? If not, should I just deploy a directory instead of a .war? Or is there a better way?

Am using glassfish.

Answer (score 0):

.war file should be unpacked by your (application) server, so your third-party lib should operate with files from unpacked .war.

Comment: Thanks! This means I'm doing something else wrong... I've marked the question as answered.

Comment: Having said that, in my final solution, it seems I DID have to deploy it as a directory for the file to be found by "getServletContext.getRealPath(...)". I'm not sure if this is supposed to work with packaged .wars too?